# What does udev rule /lib/udev/rules.d/75-net-description.rules do and can I delete it?

Tags: udev

Could someone please tell me what this udev rule is doing and if I can delete it? I am using linux as a personal computer and not a web server. I do not want a personal network, just access to the internet.

/lib/udev/rules.d/75-net-description.rules:

```
# do not edit this file, it will be overwritten on update

ACTION=="remove", GOTO="net_end"
SUBSYSTEM!="net", GOTO="net_end"

IMPORT{builtin}="net_id"

SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", IMPORT{builtin}="usb_id", IMPORT{builtin}="hwdb --subsystem=usb"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", GOTO="net_end"

SUBSYSTEMS=="pci", ENV{ID_BUS}="pci", ENV{ID_VENDOR_ID}="$attr{vendor}", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}="$attr{device}"
SUBSYSTEMS=="pci", IMPORT{builtin}="hwdb --subsystem=pci"

LABEL="net_end"
```

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with a server. This instructs udev to fill in the internal udev device property values ID_NET_NAME_ONBOARD, ID_NET_NAME_SLOT, ID_NET_NAME_PATH, ID_NET_NAME_MAC by examining the network interface device

The basic idea is to create a more or less random interface name (not `eth0` but rather something like `enp24s0`), based on some hardware info.

See [here](https://jfearn.fedorapeople.org/fdocs/en-US/Fedora/20/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Understanding_the_Device_Renaming_Procedure.html) for a comprehensive explanation of the different network UDEV rules